# Usage of "suss out" in Australian English

Tags: differences, phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs, colloquialisms, australian-english

What's the meaning of "suss out" in Australian English? (Sydney, specifically) How does it compare with "figure out"?

I've heard the verb used slightly differently than normal in a youth-related drama, though I rarely hear it from my colleagues.

Comment: It's not that frequently used in the US, but is probably understood (more or less) by most people.  I understand it to mean "figure out", though with some sort of  search or examination involved.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wiktionary, ‘suss out’ derives from the verb ‘suspect’, in this sense meaning ‘to investigate’.

It’s listed as being used in the UK, Australia, and New Zealand, though I’ve also heard it used in colloquial American English.

suss:

> 1. (transitive, UK, Australia, New Zealand, often with "out") To discover, infer or figure out.
> 2. (transitive, UK, Australia, New Zealand) To study or size up, to check out (examine). ([Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/suss))

Answer (score 2):

*OED* provides two senses of the slang verb *suss* or *sus*. The second sense is mainly used with the preposition *out* and it can be an equivalent to the phrase *figure out*. Here are the two senses and the earliest citations from *OED*:

> **1.** 
> **a.** *transitive.* To suspect (a person) of a crime (cf. sus *n.* 1). Also in general use. 
> *He turned to Hodge and said, ‘Who's sussed for this job?’* - 1953 
> **b.** With object clause: to suspect, to imagine or fancy (something) as likely; hence, to feel or surmise. 
> *He had half sused that the boggie was getting him at it.* - 1958
>
> **2.** To work or figure *out*; to investigate, to discover the truth about (a person or thing). Also with object clause and without const. 
> *Youth susses things out on its own.* - 1966

*OED* says that the verb *suss / sus* is an abbreviation of the verb *suspect* and compares to the adjective *sus* meaning "suspect, suspicious". It is also used as a noun to mean "suspicion of having committed a crime; suspicious behaviour" or "a suspected person". Additionally, *sus* has become an ubiquitous term recently, around the world, with the popular video game *Among Us*.

Moreover, *[inverse.com](https://www.inverse.com/gaming/sus-meaning-among-us-definition-origin)* provides an investigation on the slang term *sus* and here are the relevant excerpts regarding its origin in Britain; and how it crossed the pond:

> The shortening of suspicious to “sus” first took place in England and Wales as far back as the 1930s as police jargon. Instead of using it as a descriptor, like “that person is sus,” British cops would use the abbreviation to refer to the discovery of crucial evidence or information as having “sussed something out” or going on an investigation as “sussing out a situation or person.”
>
> "Sus law" was a nickname for a stop and search law enacted in 1824, that gained its monicker in the early-to-mid 1900s. It gave British law enforcement the power to search and potentially arrest people who they believed were up to no good.
>
> Since sus predates the internet, there’s no record of its first use online. But Multiple archived sources state that Black internet communities initially began using the slang on social media sites and forums.
>
> The earliest Urban Dictionary definition was posted in August 2003 by a user named Diego who defined the term as simply, “Short for ‘suspect’ or suspicious.’” Since then, sus became a common American turn of phrase that was more widely used to describe anything that makes someone raise their eyebrow.

---

*[Green's Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/kmsk3by)* lists various senses of *suss out* and provides usages within different varieties of English (American, British, Irish, Australian, South Africa). Here are the five senses listed:

> **1.** to place under suspicion. 
> **2.** to understand, to work out. 
> **3.** to discover. 
> **4.** to find attractive. 
> **5.** to select, to choose.